# How do I find my url dynamically ? HttpClient C#

Tags: c#

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:60792");
```

Instead of localhost:60792  how do I find it dynamically on start up? Pointing me in the right direction would suffice. But if you have an answer let me know.

## Update thanks for the hint. My final answer is

```
String baseURL = string.Format(
      (
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port != 80) ? "{0}://{1}:{2}" : "{0}://{1}",
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme,
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host,
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port
);
```

Comment: What url you are trying to find? What type of application do you have?

Comment: I am trying to find my root url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;`

Answer (score 0):

After the new update of Visual studio 2019 the answer by @webNoob will give an error

`'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no accessible extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

So even though you use `System.web` and `System.Net.Http` you will get the same error.

Still you can use the following as a fix:

For getting query of the string

1. For getting the query
   `var url1 = HttpContext.Request.Query.Keys;`
2. For getting the path
   `var url2 = HttpContext.Request.Path.Value;`